# How to store values for Ti.UI.createSlider(); and Ti.UI.createSwitch();?

Tags: javascript, titanium

I am using Titanium from appcelerator.com to create an iOS application.

I am using both a slider and a switch.

Both official examples showcase both how to create these things, and how to change their status, but what angers me is that nowhere do they bother to explain where and how to store these values. Seems kind of logical that if you want to place a slider or a switch somewhere, you also want to save the value user chose to select.

What would be the best or most appropriate way to do that. At the moment I am kind of puzzled, as to where I am supposed to write this data to...

I need to use this data in order to pass it to a JSON object on a server lately, if that helps to give a better answer.

Does these things have something like a database?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to achieve that :

```
var basicSlider = Titanium.UI.createSlider({
        min:1,
        max:7,
        value: Ti.App.Properties.getString('slider'),
        width:100,
        height:'auto',
        top:30,

    });

basicSlider.addEventListener('change',function(e)
    {
        Ti.App.Properties.setString('slider', basicSlider.value);
    });
```

Its quite easy when you know where to look for it! :)